# Facebook messager API webhook does not receive postback callbacks

Tags: facebook, messenger

I have a test application with a verified webhook and a connected test user in the Meta developers console. The webhook has two subscriptions: messages and messaging_postbacks. The webhook receives the messages callbacks but doesn't receive postbacks when the test user clicks postback buttons in the chat. Could you please tell what is the problem?

In the same time it receives test `messaging_postbacks` from the developer console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that subscription in the meta developers console interface doesn't
work.

[image]

It requires to sent a POST request like this

```
curl -i -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE-ID/subscribed_apps
    ?subscribed_fields=messaging_postbacks
    &access_token=PAGE-ACCESS-TOKEN"
```

See the docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhooks#subscribe-your-page

Answer (score 0):

For me, I needed to go to “Messenger” > “Settings” and then under the “Webhooks” panel, “Edit”.